# Adding Time to SpecialToDate

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, phtml, date, special-price

Magento's SpecialToDate does not include a time stamp so any deal runs until midnight.

What I would like to do is to be able to set the time as well as the date.

I was thinking of changing the SpecialToDate date attribute to a text filed, would this work?

my second option is "If the special price didn't recognize the time" where would I hard code a new atttribute(.html) that the special Price uses to check the date?

Answer (score 0):

The attributes backend is `DATETIME`, so changing the input to a text field and entering a MySQL DATETIME string should be a possible solution to store them with time.

But you will still have to modify the price index to compare dates and times.

As far as I see, you have to change [line 247-251](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php#L247-L251)  of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default` and remove `getDatePartSql()` to use the full datetime values.

Comment: Ah makes sense. I have tried removing it but didn't work. Is there something I should replace it with and How should I remove it, just getDatePartSql part?

Comment: yes, `$specialFromDate    = $write->getDatePartSql($specialFrom);` would become `$specialFromDate =   $specialFrom;`

Comment: What about currentDate? I have changed the attribute input to 'text' and in the products the time is now 2016-08-25 00:00:00. If I change the time and save, it will not update?

Comment: Looks like it's not that simple, I would have to investigate more. Probably the attribute is using a backend model that strips of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to add the Time to SpecialToDate, this is what I did.

1. Go in to Database and go to Table: `eav_attribute` and edit
   `special_to_date` change `frontend_input` from `date` to `text` and
   save.
2. Edit `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php`

   find `$date = new Zend_Date($date, $part, $locale);`

   and replace with `$date = new Zend_Date($date, $locale);`

   You can now use time with `SpecialToDate`

*Update:*

Just seen this in the same file.

```
if ($dateTo) {
$toTimeStamp += 86400;
}
```

This will need to be deleted as the date will be one day out.